Shell script installation
I wrote a shell script, and I'm trying to automate its installation. For that, I have a script that 1.) downloads the script to ~/.local/bin 2.) adds a line to .bashrc (or config.fish, etc.). The line for .bashrc looks like eval "$(myscript init bash)".
This causes bash to throw an error on login – -bash: myscript: command not found. The issue is that ~/.local/bin is added to PATH after .bashrc has been sourced (through ~/.profile).
I'm now unsure if I should either move the script to a different location or the eval statement. Here are a few things that I've considered:

It would work if I moved the eval statement to ~/.profile, but is that the right location for such a statement?
The next best place that comes to mind for the script is probably ~/bin, but that's also added to PATH after .bashrc is sourced.
/usr/local/bin could also be an option, but for that, the user would need to run the install script with sudo, which is not what I want.

What would be the best location for the script and for the eval statement, for this to work?

While modern operating systems don't honor this convention nearly as well as it used to be followed in the 90s and before,~/.profile is for things that can be run once per login session, not once per interactive shell (you can have multiple interactive shells started as child processes of a single login shell). So use .profile for things like exported variables, not for defining aliases or non-exported shell functions.

(and an exported shell function should go in .bash_profile, not .profile, since the latter is used by shells that don't support exported functions at all).

What is the problem with eval "$( ${HOME}/.local/bin/myscript init bash)"

@StefanHegny, I'd use ~ instead of ${HOME} there. Avoids some bugs, albeit ones that one would only come up in unlikely circumstances (IFS containing /, home directory containing whitespace) in addition to being shorter. Or $HOME but using a separate inner quoting context (eval "$("$HOME"/.local/bin/myscript init bash)")

I don't know what it means to install a script. Perhaps you could describe what would be the effect of that "installation". And honestly: I would probably shoot everyone who dares to fiddle with my carefully crafted .bashrc in some automated way. You probably won't make yourself many friends with what you are trying to do.

Most of this is not the job of an installer. The user should simply be responsible for ensuring that ~/.local/bin is added to their path first (as this directory is semi-standard and not under the sole purview of your code).
Once PATH is set, then the user can run your installer. It's debatable whether your installer should modify .bashrc directly (I prefer when it does not), instead simply informing the user that something like eval "$(myscript init bash)" be added to their shell session initialization.

I'm with you on team "no installer should ever try to modify my dotfiles".

I have stronger words for such installers in non-public settings :)

Then again, such practices are usually found in installers built for curl | sh invocation, and neither of us would ever run such an abomination in the first place, right? :)

Not without threat to life or limb! I have been known to save the output from curl and edit it before executing.

(that said, one thing the OP does get right in the original question is quoting the command substitution so its output doesn't get munged via word-splitting + globbing + rejoining before getting to eval).
